# Using if/elsif in my Rails method: consistently ignoring conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to write a method that does two things:

1) Checks a **Ranking** table, which contains `user_id` (integer), `game_id` (integer), and a `Ranking` of a competitor (integer), and

2) Using that ranking, updates another table called `Stack` with a number of `Chips` while recording `game_id` and `user_id`.

To test this, I am creating a records variable and then using an if/else to give a certain number of chips if a user ranks first ("1").

**ExampleModel.rb**

```
  def self.update_wallet(game_id)
    records = Ranking.where(game_id: game_id)

    records.each do |record|
      puts record.inspect
      puts record['user_id']
    if record.ranking = 1
      Stack.create(user_id: record['user_id'], game_id: game_id, chips: 50)
    elsif record.ranking = 2
      Stack.create(user_id: record['user_id'], game_id: game_id, chips: 30)
    else
      Stack.create(user_id: record['user_id'], game_id: game_id, chips: 10)
    end
  end
  end
```

In the console, the output is that it does create records for all three Rankings in the Stack table, but it is logging `Chips` as "50" (matching the first condition) even though there are three different Rankings in the array.

For my test, I am using the following data from the `Rankings` table.

`<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Ranking id: 153, game_id: 1, user_id: 1, ranking: 1, game_time: nil>, #<Ranking id: 154, game_id: 1, user_id: 2, ranking: 2, game_time: nil>, #<Ranking id: 155, game_id: 1, user_id: 3, ranking: 3, game_time: nil>`

Nonetheless, after running `Example.update_wallet(1)` in the console, it created three records matching Condition 1:

`<Stack id: 75, game_id: 1, user_id: 1, chips: 50>, #<Stack id: 76, game_id: 1, user_id: 2, chips: 50>, #<Stack id: 77, game_id: 1, user_id: 3, chips: 50>, #<Stack id: 78, game_id: 1, user_id: 1, chips: 50>, #<Stack id: 79, game_id: 1, user_id: 2, chips: 50>, #<Stack id: 80, game_id: 1, user_id: 3, chips: 50>`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to use '==' not '=' in conditions.

Comment: Rather than your rather repetitive `if/elsif/else/end` clause, consider writing `h=Hash.new(10); h.merge! { 1=>50, 2=>30 }; Stack.create(user_id: record['user_id'], game_id: game_id, chips: h[record.ranking])`. I've defined `h` with a default value of `10`, meaning that `h[k]` returns `10` if `h` does not have a key `k`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use comparison operator `==` inplace of assignment operator `=`:

```
if record.ranking == 1
  Stack.create(user_id: record['user_id'], game_id: game_id, chips: 50)
elsif record.ranking == 2
  Stack.create(user_id: record['user_id'], game_id: game_id, chips: 30)
else
  Stack.create(user_id: record['user_id'], game_id: game_id, chips: 10)
end
```

**EDIT**

Adding @CarySwoveland comment to answer.

You can avoid `if/else/end` statements using `hash`.

```
h = Hash.new(10) #default value of hash is 10 i.e h['xyz'] returns 10
h.merge!(1 => 50, 2 => 30)
Stack.create(user_id: record['user_id'], game_id: game_id, chips: h[record.ranking])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
record.ranking = 1
```

is an assignment, not comparing.

To compare `record.ranking` against 1, you should use `==`:

```
record.ranking == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an assignement of your records ranking, but your intension is to compare the ranking in the if statement.

Change

```
if record.ranking = 1
```

to

```
if record.ranking == 1
```

and

```
elsif record.ranking = 2
```

to

```
elsif record.ranking == 2
```